# angular ng repeat sum with group items

Tags: javascript, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I want group (country-wise) as well as sum of grouped elements eq. TA + TA = 150. in the column labeled by `Jan`. my plunker is http://plnkr.co/edit/Wwx3vUvhmpP8XgQJGXm2?p=preview

Thanks in advance...

```
$scope.months =  [ 
    { "mon" : "jan", "country" : "UK", "TA" : 70, "TSR" : 5164, "TP" : 2822 , "TR" : 10771},
    { "mon" : "feb", "country" : "UK", "TA" : 660, "TSR" : 6164, "TP" : 4822 , "TR" : 10771},
    { "mon" : "mar", "country" : "UK", "TA" : 57, "TSR" : 1164, "TP" : 3322 , "TR" : 20771},

    { "mon" : "jan", "country" : "Austria", "TA" : 80, "TSR" : 5164, "TP" : 2822 , "TR" : 10771},
    { "mon" : "feb", "country" : "Austria", "TA" : 67, "TSR" : 6164, "TP" : 4822 , "TR" : 10771},
    { "mon" : "mar", "country" : "Austria", "TA" : 55, "TSR" : 1164, "TP" : 3322 , "TR" : 20771}
    ];
```

My HTML is:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Jan</td>
      <td>Feb</td>
      <td>Mar</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="month in months" >
      <table >
        <tr>
          <td>{{month.TA}}</td>                                                
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ month.TSR }}</td>                                               
        </tr>                      
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I didn't understood you but I think in this case you may need to make a function in the $scope so you can call it in the ngRepeat, you may set params in the function to know what to sum

Comment: Hi, I have added plunker in my question.. please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
$scope.GetSummOfAges=function(group){
  var summ=0;
  for(var i in group.data)
  {
    summ=summ+Number(group.data[i].age);
  }
  return summ;
};
```

Comment: OK, let me see if i can find something for you